# how to call a js function in a view file

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

This is part of code from my view file (i'm using CI):

```
<td class="last">
  <a href="<?php echo base_url('settings/apconfiguration/edit_ap/'.$ap['MAC_Address']); ?>">edit</a>
  | <a href="  <script> if (checkYesNoAnswerOfUser()) </script></a> <?php echo base_url('settings/apconfiguration/deleteAp/'.$ap['MAC_Address'].'/'.$ap['AP_State']); ?>">delete</a>
</td>
```

I have a js function `checkYesNoAnswerOfUser()` that returns `1` or `0`, and according to it I want the `delete`  to do nothing ot something (call deleteAp...).

`checkYesNoAnswerOfUser()` is in .js file.

I don't understand how to make this work.

Comment: Include the js file in your code
<script type = "text/javascript" src="path_to_your_file"></script>

Comment: You should read about unobtrusive javascript, and how to handle it [via jQuery for instance].

Comment: Why is there a script in a href attribute?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confused, javascript runs in client side, and PHP runs in server side, therefore, when php runs, PHP don't know that javascript function "checkYesNoAnswerOfUser()" exists.

The correct way is generate this url : base_url('settings/apconfiguration/deleteAp/'.$ap['MAC_Address'].'/'.$ap['AP_State']) with javascript OR make the function "checkYesNoAnswerOfUser" with PHP